# The link color in the navigation bar is unchangeable

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

This is my code
 `
    
    
        My Personal Website

```
<style>
    html body{
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        }
    .navbar-container {
        position: absolute;
        top:0;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #283018;
        }
    .navigation-bar {
        padding: 10px;
        }

    .nav-ul {
        padding-top: 7px;
        overflow:hidden;
        padding-left: 540px;
        list-style-type:none;

        }

    .nav-ul  li {

        color: white;
        display: inline;
        padding:50px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 1.1em;
        float:left-inline;

        }
     .navbar-name h1    {
        color: white;
        float:left;
        padding-left: 2px;
        font-size: 1.5em;
        }

    .navbar-links a:link {
        color: white;
        text-decoration:none;
        }
    li a:link {
        color:white;
        }
    .navbar-links li:hover, .navbar-links a:hover  {
        background-color: blue;
        }


</style>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar-container">
        <div class="navigation-bar">
        <div class="navbar-name">
            <h1>Welcome to My Personal Site</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-links">
            <ul class="nav-ul">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">My Works</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>`
```

I can't change the link in the navbar.
this is the code that must change the link color but it can't

```
.navbar-links a:link {
        color: white;
        text-decoration:none;
        }
```

I even tried to put 
`li a:link` 
but it does not work

The link color is unchangeable.

Sorry but I can't post screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
.navbar-links li a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration:none;
 }
```